# AccuRev, How to check whether a stream is "pass-through" or not?

Tags: accurev

Using AccuRev version 5.7

I know that the "show" command would show information about a stream.

```
show [ -f<format(s)> ] [ -p <depot> ] [ -d ] [ -t <time-spec> ]
    [ -s <stream> [ -m[<match-type>] ] [ -r | -R | -1 ] ] streams
```

But the "Dyn" column shown in the result only tells it's "dynamic" or not.

```
(Dyn) a “Y” if the stream is dynamic.
```

So, how can I tell whether a stream is "pass-through" or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the -fx option, see the type entry.
[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I've got to agree that "-fx" gives more information.